# Retrieve primary key from GridView via Checkbox for SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I am following on a tutorial from [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs).

But I got jammed at the part where I need to grep the primary key of the checked rows.

Below is my current code:

```
protected void DeleteChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool atLeastOneRowDeleted = false;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("UserSelector");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {

            atLeastOneRowDeleted = true;

            int employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like " +employeeID;
            SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know what I should change and how do I grep my 'Employee' variable on my GridView so that I can insert it into my DELETE statement.

Below is my sample GridView and the error I am meeting now.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "C# SQL Visual Studio". That's what we use tags for on [so]. Also, your question is about .NET, not Visual Studio. You would have had the same problem if you were writing your code in Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on that line and look at the value of GridView1.DataKeys. I bet there are no keys in that array, so DataKeys[0] will throw that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
int employeeID= Convert.Toint32(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells["Employee"].Value);
```